# Action script tutorial?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Hi I am a Student in Norway looking for a good general tutorial on Action Script and how to use it,and what it's for.
I have been looking around google for a while and I can't seem to find any good or "simple" way to learn or even understand how it works.

sites i've been too:

- (http://www.actionscript.org/resources/categories/Tutorials/)
- (http://www.flashandmath.com/)
- (http://tutorials.flashmymind.com/)
- (http://tutorialoutpost.com/tutorials/flash/actionscript)
- (http://www.tutorialguide.net/programming/actionscript/)
- (http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/actionscript/)
- (http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flash/index.htm)
- (http://www.freeprogrammingresources.com/actionscript.html)
- (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript.html)

So what do I want to know ?

- Basic scripting to advanced scripting.
- Where it's best to use action script. (best functions)
- A simple yet efficient explenation that alot of people might understand.(if possible)

So if there is any way you guys might be able to help me with this little problem of mine I would be forever in your debt.

and thanks in advance for any info that might come my way, even if it helps me or not.

Comment: What are you intending to use ActionScript for? Or are you just curious to know what ActionScript is? Are you trying to solve a specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this too: http://www.gotoandlearn.com/. It has some good free tutorials, but if I remember correctly, you need to pay for the full series!..

And the best approach to learn something is to read the documentation while working on something! Try create a game/small site/interactive animation/etc and when you are stuck, search the answer or ask for help!

Answer (score 0):

ActionScript is similar to Java and C++ but different. It runs on the Flash Player. It is generally used for applications ranging from online games to video players to Rich Internet Applications.

Flash can be developed from 2 perspectives:

- Designer's perspective: This approach consists of drawing objects, shapes etc on a stage like you do in an image editing software, and then animating / adding actions to the drawn objects. You develop this in Flash Professional ([Link here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flash_cs5_createfla.html))
- Developer's perspective: This approach consists of developing using the Flex framework, from an IDE ([Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder/features.html))

Check these out. I learnt it by looking at various tutorials on the net (do a Google search, you'll find plenty), so you can learn from the net as you go.

Answer (score 0):

I often recommend Colin Moock's Lost Actionscript Week End video tutorials , it's an excellent resource if you want to grasp the general concept behind AS3 and leaves you with enough understanding so that you're able to tackle books on Object Oriented programming, AS3 language reference, basically tools that you will eventually need when you get deeper into the subject.

http://tv.adobe.com/show/colin-moocks-lost-actionscript-weekend

Answer (score 0):

Why don´t you try the official Google Action Script documentation? You can find it at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/ . I fount it very useful and easy to understand... It is very well organized and there are many examples with diverse grade of complexity. For example: you have there 5-minutes overview for your first Google Action Scrpipt https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview#what_can_apps_script_do

And if you are looking for a more complex example, you can go forward to end-to-end examples: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/bracket_maker

That is my first reference point with Google Action Script...